# Mockery - Unexpected Expectations - Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, jmock

I have a service with the following interface :

```
public interface accountsService {

    public accountRemovalModel purgeAccounts();
}
```

I have to following test class :

I have a service with the following interface :

```
public interface AccountsService {

    public accountRemovalModel purgeAccounts();
}
```

I have to following test class :

```
public class AccountsServiceTest extends BaseTestClass {

    private Mockery _m = new Mockery() {
    {
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }};


    private accountsService _accountsService;

    @Before
    public void beforeTests() throws Exception {

        accountsService = _m.mock(AccountsService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoItemsToDeleteSuccess() throws Exception {

        // Return a simple AccountsRemovalModel
        // APPARENTLY THIS EXPECTATION IS UNEXPECTED?
        _m.checking(new Expectations() {{

            allowing(accountsService.purgeAccounts());
            will(returnValue(new accountRemovalModel(0,0)));
        }});

        accountsRemovalModel result = accountsService.purgeAccounts();

        Assert.assertEquals(0, result.getDeleteCount());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, result.getTotalCount());
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error :

AccountsServiceTest.testNoItemsToDeleteSuccess:23 » Expectation unexpected...

Any help with this is greatly appreciated - as I am having big problems with getting this to work!

Comment: you don't use mockito but jmockit. I updated tags

Comment: You are correct, that was me having an idiot moment - We normally use mockito - and in this project we use jmockit.

Comment: Sorry, JMock :) Sorry  I don't know it but you seem mock the method of the method under test. You should not.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is slightly off - you need parentheses around the object being mocked (`accountsService`):

```
    _m.checking(new Expectations() {{

        allowing(accountsService).purgeAccounts();
        will(returnValue(new accountRemovalModel(0,0)));
    }});
```